# How to get src from an image before it is changed to use it later?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a file preview and I had an issue while creating a function to remove the image uploaded. I need to create a function that removes the image uploaded and shows the default picture that I have. Let's suppose that I have an account with a picture and then I want to change it, but when I uploaded a file I didn't like it and want to click in a button that will remove this new picture and get back to the first one (let's say that I didn't save it). So, in all cases I need to store the first src in a variable and then use it later if it's necessary. I'll reproduce here the code that I created to preview the file (it's working good). Now I need help to create the **remove function** following the requirements I said before. If it's possible, **without jquery**.

```
const inpFile = document.getElementById("inpFile");
const previewContent = document.getElementById("imagePreview");
const previewDefaultText = previewContainer.querySelector(".previewText");
const previewImage = previewContent.querySelector(".previewImage");


    inpFile.addEventListener("change", function(){
      const file = this.files[0];

      if(file){
        const reader = new FileReader();
        previewDefaultText.style.display = "none";
        previewImage.style.display = "block";
        reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
          previewImage.setAttribute("src", this.result);
        });
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the original source in a `dataset` property.

```js
inpFile.addEventListener("change", function() {
  const file = this.files[0];
  if (!previewImage.dataset.origSrc) {
    previewImage.dataset.origSrc = previewImage.src;
  }
  if (file) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    previewDefaultText.style.display = "none";
    previewImage.style.display = "block";
    reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
      previewImage.setAttribute("src", this.result);
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
})

removeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (previewImage.dataset.origSrc) {
    previewImage.src = previewImage.dataset.origSrc;
    previewImage.dataset.origSrc = '';
  }
});
```